# Batch script does launch the application but does not close it

Tags: windows, batch-file

Requirement :- I am trying to automate this task using below batch script

Task :-

> Launch DOORS application 
>   Close it after 3 min, 
>   Relaunch the application again

Note :-  I want to run same task 5 times.

SCRIPT I am running is the follow , it does launch the application but does not close it..please suggest. Am I doing something here in this script

```
set counter=0
:loop
start "Hey" "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.3\bin\doors.exe"
timeout /t 180 >null
taskkill /f /im "doors.exe*32" >nul
timeout /t 7 >null
SET /A counter=%counter%+1
if %counter% GTR 5
(GOTO exit) else (GOTO loop)
:exit
exit `
```

Comment: Try the taskkill without the *32.

Comment: I tried without *32,it did not work. I tested this on Windows 7.